# Issues while build a local php site with wordpress in a sub-directory

Tags: php, wordpress, docker

We use Docker, Docker-compose and Webpack to build a local environment for a php site. Recently I was tasked with adding a blog to the local setup using wordpress. I have been able to get everything up and running almost how I intended however there have been some issues with live reloading of the site. I can not for the life of me get the setup to work so that both the site root files and the blog sub-directory files will live-reload when saved. I can get either or too work but just not both. We use the browser sync plugin in webpack to reload any change it sees to the dist folder.

I believe the issue comes from the volume mount in the docker-compose file. If I mount only the wordpress wp-content files:

```
volumes:
   - ./dist/blog/wp-content/uploads:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/uploads
   - ./dist/blog/wp-content/plugins:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins
   - ./dist/blog/wp-content/themes:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/themes
```

The wordpress blog gets updated upon save but any files not under blog/ do not. If I have the root folder mounted in volumes all files but the WordPress files reload. 
    volumes:
        - ./dist:/var/www/html

And when I exec into the blog folder it has erased or overwritten the entire wordpress installation so they the WP site can no longer be used. If I have all four lines in same result. I am not sure if anyone can help me but I hope someone has ran into this issue before and I appreciate any help you can give. I have tried to include my relevant file info. LEt me know If I need to add more

**dist folder structure**

```
dist/
  blog/
    wp-content/
      themes/
        custom-themes/
          .... theme-files
  index.php
  contactus.php
  about.php
  ... etc
```

**dockerfile**

```
FROM php:7.0-apache

# Run Linux apt (Advanced Package Tool) to and install any packages
RUN apt-get update && \
  apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends
RUN docker-php-ext-install mysqli && docker-php-ext-enable mysqli
# Enable mod_rewrite in apache modules
RUN a2enmod rewrite

# Manually set up the apache environment variables
ENV APACHE_RUN_USER www-data
ENV APACHE_RUN_GROUP www-data
ENV APACHE_LOG_DIR /var/log/apache2
ENV APACHE_LOCK_DIR /var/lock/apache2
ENV APACHE_PID_FILE /var/run/apache2.pid

# Expose apache.
EXPOSE 80

ADD ves-apache-config.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf

WORKDIR /var/www/html/

COPY ./dist /var/www/html/

WORKDIR /var/www/html/blog/

# Set our wordpress environment variables
ENV WORDPRESS_VERSION 5.2.2
ENV WORDPRESS_SHA1 3605bcbe9ea48d714efa59b0eb2d251657e7d5b0

# Download and unpack wordpress
RUN set -ex; \
  curl -o wordpress.tar.gz -fSL "https://wordpress.org/wordpress-${WORDPRESS_VERSION}.tar.gz"; \
  echo "$WORDPRESS_SHA1 *wordpress.tar.gz" | sha1sum -c -; \
  # upstream tarballs include ./wordpress/ so this gives us /usr/src/wordpress
  tar -xzf wordpress.tar.gz -C /var/www/html/blog; \
  rm wordpress.tar.gz; \
  chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/blog

RUN cp -r /var/www/html/blog/wordpress/. /var/www/html/blog/

RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/blog/wordpress.tar.gz
RUN rm -rf /var/www/html/blog/wordpress

CMD ["apache2-foreground"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3"
services:
  server:
    # Name our container
    container_name: corporate-site
    environment:
      - COMPOSE_CONVERT_WINDOWS_PATHS=1
    depends_on:
      - database
    build:
      context: ./
    volumes:
      # - ./dist:/var/www/html
      - ./dist/blog/wp-content/uploads:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/uploads
      - ./dist/blog/wp-content/plugins:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/plugins
      - ./dist/blog/wp-content/themes:/var/www/html/blog/wp-content/themes
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
    # Logging Control
    logging:
      driver: none
  ### MYSQL DATABASE ###
  database:
    container_name: blog-database
    build:
      context: ./config/docker/database
    volumes:
      - datab:/var/lib/mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
volumes:
  datab:
```

**Webpack file**

```
module.exports = merge(base, {
 mode: 'development',
 devtool: 'inline-source-map',
 watch: true,
 plugins: [
  new BrowserSyncPlugin({
   host: 'localhost',
   proxy: 'http://localhost:8080',
   port: 3200,
   open: true,
   files: [
    './dist/*.php',
    './dist/blog/wp-content/themes/blog/*.php',
    './dist/blog/wp-content/themes/blog/*.css'
   ]
  }),
 ]
})
```

Comment: did you try to mount just `./dist/blog/wp-content` ?

Comment: @LinPy thanks for your reply, If I mount just the ```./dis/blog/wp-content``` it is the same result as if I mount the three wp-content folders above. All wordpress files are updated but nothing outside of the '''/blog/''' directory. The root site files are still not reloaded. Browsersync reloads the pages so it detects changes however docker isn't serving them.

Comment: The root site files are in '''./dist/''' and then in '''/dist/''' there is '''/blog/''' with wordpress in it but If I mount just '''/dist/''' folder which also includes '''/blog/''' wordpress installation again is erased.

Comment: then I think you can try to mount the wordpress intsallation files and remove that step from your dockerfile, then you can mount the ./dist including all the files required

Comment: Sorry, would you mind showing me an example of what you mean? Remove the volume mounts in docker-compose and replace with just '''/dist/:var/www/html/''' but not sure what I am removing from Dockerfile. thanks for your continued help and patience.

Comment: I add an Example as an Answer